# Trying to use setBackground for a mouse listener on a jButton, but it gives an error over the word "Color"

Tags: java

jButton3.setBackground(Color.Blue);

Trying to use this and it says cannot find symbol when I hover over the error on the word "Color". Do I need to import another package or something? Figured everything was in swing, so I would assume there's another issue with what I am doing. Any help would be great!

I've tried looking for other people having a similar issue, but can't seem to find others with it. Some things to note, jButton3 is already initialized, and this is for a mouse listener so that when the user hovers over the button it will change to a darker color. Also, the color blue will change but doubt that matters for this issue.[image]

Edit: I added a suggested package and it works now. I'm not sure why "import java.awt.Color;" was necessary since other color changes have worked, but it works as intended now.

Edit2: Well new question anyone know how to change to a specific rgb code?

Comment: Do you mean something like `~.setForeground (new Color (89,58,102))` ?

Comment: the fully qualified name of the `Color` class is `java.awt.Color` since it is in the `java.awt` package. You could have written `setBackground(java.awt.Color.BLUE)` Using the import statement, you can refer to a class using its single name.